# Problema al intentar subir nueva version appbundle en play store console

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play-console

Tengo un aviso de error cuando intento subir actualizacion por segunda vez (version 2) la app tipo appbundle a play console, que me dice "El código de versión 1 ya se ha usado. Prueba con otro código de versión."
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No logro solucionar este error cuando subo el appbundle a playstore
ya he cambiado la version desde el pubspec.yaml y desde otros archivos como build.gradle
que me recomiendan hacer?

tengo esto:

build.gradle, (antes las tenia en '1')

```
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '2'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '2.0'
}
```

pubspec.yaml, antes lo tenia como (version: 1.0.1+1)

```
version: 2.0.1+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

Necessita cambiar el fin de version. Usa este en su pubspec.yaml:

```
version: 1.0.2+2
```

Sigueinte versions: 1.0.3+3, 1.0.4+4 ...